# Is it okay to "take the limit outside of a function" by assuming "the inner limit exists"?

Tags: calculus, limits

We know, if $f(x)$ is continuous at $b = \lim_{x\to a}g(x)~;[b \in \Re]$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f(b) = f( \lim_{x\to a} g(x) )
$$
Which also holds for one-sided limits as well.

Say, using this result, we are to find the limit
$$
\lim_{ x \to 0^{+} } x^x \\ [(g(x)=x^x \text{ and } a = 0)]
$$

I encountered a solution where it's assumed that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x^x = b~~~~~...~~~(1)$$

which implies
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln(b) &=& \ln (\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x^x) \\
&=& \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} (\ln(x^x)) ; ~~[\text{Applying the above theorem}]\\
&=& \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x \ln(x) \\
&=& \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/x} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\rightarrow \frac{-\infty}{\infty}\\
&=& \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2} \\
&=& \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} -x\\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
$$
b = \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = e^0 = 1 ~~~~~~\textbf{(Ans.)}
$$
My problem is with equation (1). It assumes that the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x$$

**(a)** exists,
**(b)** is finite
**(c)** is positive.
(b) & (c) are understandable, but they may not be in other similar problems.

**QUESTIONS**
**{1}** How to know if these assumptions are true?
**{2}** If assuming such a thing as equation (1) leads us to an answer (in this case, 1), does that mean the assumption was true in the first place? Why so?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're stating arises from the fact that the solution contains an algebraic manipulation of the limit. In most cases this issue can be avoided if you do the manipulation *before* taking the limit.

So in this case, for any $x>0$, we have $x^x = e^{x \ln x}$. Then we calculate that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x = 0$ exactly as you do, and *then* we use the theorem you have stated at the top. Thus, by the continuity of the exponential,

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x = \lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{x\ln x} = e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x} = e^0 = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks, it's a good way of avoiding such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Finiteness of the limit doesn't seem necessary. Note: $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1x=\alpha\implies\ln(\alpha)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(\frac1x)=-\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln(x)=-(-\infty)=\infty\implies\alpha=\infty$$